# How to Make XML Templates In Angular 7

Tags: xml, angular, typescript

How to pass XML value in Angular 7
API accept this type of XML code

```
-modifydata "<datasets><dataset select=\""always\"">
<replace match=\""Letter/@FName\"" value=\""Nazeeeeeeeeeeeeer\""/>
<replace match=\""Letter/@LName\"" value=\""Waqasay\""/>
</dataset></datasets>"
```

when I modified it and add "\" its became hidden need help to bind it with code in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Use following snippet to make a XML

```
    const toValue = 'John doe';
    const fromValue = 'Smith';
    const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <note>
                  <to>${toValue}</to>
                  <from>${fromValue}</from>
                  <heading>Reminder</heading>
                  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                </note>`;
```